# Epplus pivot table with date grouping not sorting dates correctly

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I programmatically create a pivot table from data with timestamps using epplus. I put the timestamp field on the `RowFields` list and add by-day and by-month grouping to the `ExcelPivotTableField` (`.AddDateGrouping(eDateGroupBy.Days | eDateGroupBy.Months`).

When I open the file with Excel (2010), the date column sorts like "10-Oct", "11-Oct"... "30-Oct", "1-Oct", "2-Oct"... ending on "9-Oct". If I remove the "Days" grouping and add it back, everything is normal (i.e. starts at "1-Oct" and ends with "30-Oct").

Right-click -> "Refresh" has no effect; source data and pivot column formatting has no effect.

[Edit:] I opened [an issue on Github](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/44) about this